# Executing shell script from ruby script

Tags: ruby, shell

I have the following:

```
_shellScript = "../Dependency/test.sh"
exec 'sh #{_shellScript}'
```

But when I go to execute the ruby script it ends me up at a shell prompt instead of executing the script that is located within the variable _shellScript.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Your code uses single quotes in the `exec` string. In single quote strings Ruby does not provide interpolation (`#{}`). That could aslo be the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ruby, `exec` ends the Ruby process and passes the shell to the child specified. If you need to give all of `test.sh`'s output to your console, you want `system("sh #{_shellScript}")`. If  you need to give data and receive it through stdin and stdout, look at `popen`.

Comment: I think your comment might be closer to the real problem, the `#` in `'sh #{_shellScript}'` will be seen as a comment so it will be the same as saying `exec 'sh'` and there's command prompt.

Comment: You might be fixing the current bug (single instead of double quotes) and the next one (`exec` instead of `system`) at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

Just try the following line:

```
%x[#{_shellScript}]
```